# DataStax opscenterd won't start on Ubuntu 15.04 x64

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cassandra, opscenter, ubuntu-15.04

Issue:

> sudo service opscenterd start
>   Failed to start opscenterd.service: Unit opscenterd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
>   (ERROR)-(Exit Code 6)-(Unknown error code)
>
> sudo service opscenterd status
>   opscenterd.service
>      Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
>      Active: inactive (dead)

Config

> [webserver]
>   port = 8888
>   interface = 0.0.0.0

I tried another port and ip (localhost)

- Cassandra installed and running (dsc21, cassandra 2.1.10)
- no log files been generated in /var/log/opscenter/
- opscenter installed via apt-get (5.2)

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issues as you, seems like OpsCenter could not run as service on Ubuntu 15, I went running it as background process and it works,
try:

$ sudo your_opscenter_install_path/bin/opscenter

hope helpping